# How to manually import RandomColorSwift github project to XCode project?

Tags: xcode, github

I am trying to ***manually import*** [RandomColorSwift](https://github.com/onevcat/RandomColorSwift) github file to my XCode project, but I am confused by the directions below:

> **Manually**
>
> If you need to support iOS 7.x, you will need to add the library
>   manually into your project since dynamic framework is not supported
>   for iOS 7.
>
> Clone this repo and throw the source files under `RandomColor` folder
>   into your project to use it.

What do they mean by "add the library manually" and "clone this repo"? Do they want me to download the zip file?

Is the "source files" the `RandomColor` folder that contains ColorDefinition.swift, Hue.swift, etc?

Comment: Just add all the source files to your project and have them compile side by side with your own classes?

Comment: "clone" is to download a copy of the repository (with all the internal structure necessary for version management) to a directory of your computer. It contains all the history of the changes to all files.  Downloading the zip, you only get the latest version of all files.

Comment: Hi, I am confused by what "source files" actually refer to. Are the "source files" all the files in the RandomColor folder?

Comment: " Are the "source files" all the files in the RandomColor folder?" : that depends on the directory  structure of that particular project.

Comment: Yes, whatever is in the RandomColor folder. Good luck Amanda, I look forward to seeing more swift-related questions from you.

Comment: You are coding an app in Swift; I assume you **do** know what a source file is?

Comment: I checked the repo's page on GiHub. It seems that you need all the files inside the folder `RandomColor`, **except** "info.plist" (that seems to be specific to the Demo app. Your project already has its own info.plist).

Comment: "The easiest way to use RandomColor is installing it by CocoaPods". That is, provided you know what CocoaPods is and have a minimum of experience using them.